# Vim: Highlight C++ variables using scope?

Tags: c++, vim, syntax-highlighting, scope

I would like to have C++ variables highlighted by scope. E.g. variables should have different coloring depending on file, class, global or local scope. Is it possible?

UPDATE: External helpers (e.g. ctags/clang and vim scripts) are welcome.

UPDATE 2: This really should be possible using libclang. Take a look at Doug Gregor presentations here: http://llvm.org/devmtg/2010-11/  I think just no one has done it yet... or?

Comment: Unless csope and friends do some magic that I am unaware of, I don't think this is possible.  Vim's syntax highlighting is done via regex matching.  It has no concept of scope.

Comment: @Randy “Vim's syntax highlighting is done via regex matching.” – Not quite. It’s true that it uses regex to match individual lexemes but it actually uses a pushdown machine so it can (at least theoretically) match all nonregular context free languages. But as to the question, I am unaware of such a script and similar scripts that promise extended C++ support (OmniCppComplete …) fail to live up to their promises.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2646

From the script website:

> This set of scripts is designed to increase the number of highlighting groups used by Vim.  This makes it quicker and easier to spot errors in your code.  By using ctags and parsing the output, the typedefs, #defines, enumerated names etc are all clearly highlighted in different colors.

There are some screenshots available to show the comparison.

http://sites.google.com/site/abudden/contents/Vim-Scripts/ctags-highlighting

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't really do what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

One trick I have seen but don;t use:

If you declare your variables with the appropriate prefix g_, m_ etc.. You can use this to get vim to colour them differently:

Comment: I actually prefer that - reason I ask is I switched workplace, the new one doesn't use scope prefixes.

Comment: I dislike that naming convention (no particular justifiable reason). I just like my variable names to be meaningful and easy to read (I don't have many global variables (usually 0) so g_ seems redundant) If I can't tell the difference between a local and a member variable I tend to refactor the code to make it easier to read.